# Problem in adding input with similar class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem adding an input with similar class(`addinput_units`).

In the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/FpsPh/) when you click on the "add" link next to "field 1", it adds a new input following "field 2" with value "field 1".

How can I add a new field following the input nearest to the "add" link with a similar class(`addinput_units`) in HTML?

**EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/FpsPh/

```
$(function () {
    $('a.add_input').live('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $class = '.' + $(this).closest('div.find_input').find('div').attr('class').split(" ")[0];
        var newDiv = $($(this).closest($class).get(0)).clone(false);
        $(this).closest($class).find('.add_input:first').remove()
        newDiv.hide().fadeIn('slow');
        $($class + ':last').after(newDiv);
    });
});
```

**EDITE:**

this is the original my code that not work true. see you: http://jsfiddle.net/FpsPh/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understood the question, but is this what you're going for?

```
$(function () {
    $('a.add_input').live('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
            $div = $this.closest('div'),
            $clone = $div.clone().hide()
                .insertAfter($div).fadeIn('slow');
        $this.remove();
    });
});
```

Here's the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FpsPh/1/).

Comment: this is the original my code that not work true. see you: http://jsfiddle.net/FpsPh/4/

Comment: I've updated your jsfiddle with my JavaScript (http://jsfiddle.net/FpsPh/5/), and it still works the way I'm expecting.  If this is not the behavior you want, can you try to explain the desired behavior again?  I had trouble understanding your initial question.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are selecting the last `addinput_units` div in the document, not the one in the correct `td`.  Use closest:

```
$('a.add_input').live('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $class = '.' + $(this).closest('div.find_input').find('div').attr('class').split(" ")[0];
    var newDiv = $(this).closest($class).clone(false);
    newDiv.hide().fadeIn('slow');
    $(this).closest($class).append(newDiv).find('.add_input:first').remove()
});
```

You also don't need to call `get(0)` on the closest - it will only ever return one element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FpsPh/2/

Comment: this in the original my code not work true. see you: http://jsfiddle.net/FpsPh/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `prev()` instead of `closest()`? Or maybe a different method of finding the element. Maybe matching an ID to it and changing the link's ID, try playing around with different types of ways to find the element you want to clone.

Comment: this is the original my code that not work true. see you: http://jsfiddle.net/FpsPh/4/